# spring-jooq with transaction not working

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, jooq

While integrating spring with jooq the transactional declarative roll back function not working . My settings in application-context.xml are below

```
<bean id="transactionManager1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <qualifier value="tx-jooqtest"/>
     <property name="dataSource" value="#{jooqtest.getDataSource()}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jooqtest" class="com.vassarlabs.datasource.service.impl.VLDataSource">
    <property name="dataStoreName" value="jooqtest" />
</bean>
```

And After then I have a method tagged with transactional like below

```
@Transactional(value = "tx-jooqtest" , rollbackFor = DataAccessException.class)
public void testTransaction() {
    DSLContext dslContext = null;

       dslContext = DSL.using(dtSource.getDataSource(), SQLDialect.MYSQL);
    String sql = "insert into food (kind) values ( ? )";            
    dslContext.execute(sql ,new Object[]{"Its a whole next level kind "} );                     
    insert2();}
```

and in insert2() method I am throwing DataAccessExcpetion  , But transaction is not getting rolled back . Is there any other properties I have to set in application-context xml to make it work .

Comment: For the record, this question was also asked on the [jOOQ manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/transaction-management/#comment-3271116066)

Comment: I think in order for someone to be able to answer this question (regardless on Stack Overflow or on the jOOQ manual), you will need to add the code for: `insert2()`, your `VLDataSource`. I still believe that your problem is inside of that `VLDataSource`, but it's hard to tell from what information you've given so far.

Comment: Seems like it was missing some configuration . Instead of DSL.using(dataSource ,  dialect) , I have to use DSL.using(connProvider , dialect) and below properties in application-context.xml.                                                    **`<bean id="transactionAwareDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
  <constructor-arg value="#{jooqtest.getDataSource()}" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.jooq.impl.DataSourceConnectionProvider" name="connectionProvider">
    <constructor-arg ref="transactionAwareDataSource" />         
 </bean>`**

Answer (score 1):

Seems like some properties were missing in application-context.xml . In order for jooq to realise that spring transaction to be part of same transaction as jooq , We have to create a connection provider bean which refers to dataSource via TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy. Updated Code and configuration are below

```
 @Transactional(value = "tx-jooqtest" , rollbackFor = DataAccessException.class)                                           
     public void testTransaction() {
     DSLContext dslContext = null;
     dslContext = DSL.using(connProvider, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
     String sql = "insert into food (kind) values ( ? )";            
      dslContext.execute(sql ,new Object[]{"Its a whole next level kind "} 
    );                     
    insert2();}
```

platform-application-context.xml

```
    <bean id="transactionManager1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <qualifier value="tx-jooqtest"/>
         <property name="dataSource" value="#{jooqtest.getDataSource()}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jooqtest" class="com.vassarlabs.datasource.service.impl.VLDataSource">
        <property name="dataStoreName" value="jooqtest" />
    </bean>
<bean id="transactionAwareDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
        <constructor-arg value="#{jooqtest.getDataSource()}" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.jooq.impl.DataSourceConnectionProvider" name="connectionProvider">
        <constructor-arg ref="transactionAwareDataSource" />
    </bean>
```